# What is a "query parameter" in C++?

Tags: c++, sql, db2, stringstream

We were using stringstream to prepare select queries in C++. But we were strongly advised to use QUERY PARAMETERS to submit db2 sql queries to avoid using of stringstream. Can anyone share what exactly meant by query parameter in C++? Also, share some practical sample code snippets.

Appreciate the help in advance.

Edit: It is stringstream and not strstream.

Thanks,
Mathew Liju

Comment: This question relates to SQL, not C++; but I'm not an SQL expert, so I'll let others actually answer the question. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this refers to parameterized queries in general, rather than constructing the query in a string, they supply sql variables (or parameters) and then pass those variables separately.  These are much better for handling SQL Injection Attacks.  To illustrate with an example:

```
"SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId = " + _customerId;
```

Is bad, while this:

```
"SELECT * FROM Customers where CustomerId = @CustomerId"
```

is good.  The catch is that you have to add the parameters to the query object (I don't know how this is done in C++.

References to other questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-attacks
- [Stored Procedures vs Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230668/stored-procedures-vs-parameterized-queries)

Wild Wild Web:

- http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/database/database-tip-use-parameterized-queries.html

Answer (score 1):

Sql query in parameterized query form is safe than  string format to avoid sql injection attack.
Example of parameterized query

```
StringBuilder sqlstr = new StringBuilder();  
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyid", CompanyID);  
sqlstr.Append("SELECT evtconfigurationId, companyid, 
  configname, configimage FROM SCEVT_CONFIGURATIONS ");
sqlstr.Append("WHERE companyid=@companyid ");
```

Example of  query string format

```
StringBuilder sqlstr = new StringBuilder();   
sqlstr.Append("SELECT evtconfigurationId, companyid, configname, 
   configimage FROM SCEVT_CONFIGURATIONS ");
sqlstr.Append("WHERE companyid" +  CompanyID);
```