# way to check multiple filetypes

Tags: c++

I have written a program which would categorize files based on their extensions.As of now,I am grouping them by if-else conditions[code below].I am planning to use a separate class and then in that class keep all the document types.Any more simple implementations are welcome.

```
if(it->path().extension() == ".txt"||it->path().extension() == ".doc"||it->path().extension() == ".docx"||it->path().extension() == ".pdf") 
    {   
        f[0].filePath=it->path();
        f[0].fileName=it->path().filename();
        f[0].fileExt=it->path().extension();

        query="Insert into Filemanager(Filepath,Filename,Category)values('" + f[0].filePath.string() + "','" + f[0].fileName.string() + "','Documents')";       
    }
    else if(it->path().extension() == ".mp3"||it->path().extension() == ".wma") 
    {      
        f[1].filePath=it->path();
        f[1].fileName=it->path().filename();
        f[1].fileExt=it->path().extension();            
        query="Insert into Filemanager(Filepath,Filename,Category)values('" + f[0].filePath.string() + "','" + f[0].fileName.string() + "','Music')";       
    }
    else if(it->path().extension() == ".mp4") 
    {          
        f[2].filePath=it->path();
        f[2].fileName=it->path().filename();
        f[2].fileExt=it->path().extension();            
        query="Insert into Filemanager(Filepath,Filename,Category)values('" + f[0].filePath.string() + "','" + f[0].fileName.string() + "','Videos')";      
    }
    else if(it->path().extension() == ".jpg"||it->path().extension() == ".jpeg"||it->path().extension() == ".gif") 
    {          
        f[3].filePath=it->path();
        f[3].fileName=it->path().filename();
        f[3].fileExt=it->path().extension();            
        query="Insert into Filemanager(Filepath,Filename,Category)values('" + f[0].filePath.string() + "','" + f[0].fileName.string() + "','Pictures')";        
    }
    else 
    {     
        f[4].filePath=it->path();
        f[4].fileName=it->path().filename();
        f[4].fileExt=it->path().extension();            
        query="Insert into Filemanager(Filepath,Filename,Category)values('" + f[0].filePath.string() + "','" + f[0].fileName.string() + "','Others')";      
    }
```

I want to avoid if-else conditions.Thanks in advance.

Final Reworked code:

```
std::map<string,string> docTypes = boost::assign::map_list_of (".txt", "Documents") (".pdf", "Documents") (".pdf", "Documents") (".rtf", "Documents")
                                                                                        (".jpg", "Pictures") (".jpeg", "Pictures") (".gif", "Pictures")
                                                                                        (".mp3", "Audio") (".mp4", "Audio")
                                                                                        (".wma", "Video") (".flv", "Video");        
f[0].filePath=it->path();
    f[0].fileName=it->path().filename();
    std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator docIterator=docTypes.find(it->path().extension().string());
    if( docIterator != docTypes.end() ) 
    {
         category = docIterator->second;
    }
    else
    {
        category="Others";
    }
    query="Insert into Filemanager(Filepath,Filename,Category)values('" + f[0].filePath.string() + "','" + f[0].fileName.string() + "','" + category + "')";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:  (I didn't compile it so it may have some errors)

```
std::map<std::string,int> extMap;

// put your extensions here...
extMap.insert( std::pair<std::string,int>(".txt", 0) );
extMap.insert( std::pair<std::string,int>(".doc", 0) );

extMap.insert( std::pair<std::string,int>(".mp3", 1) );
...

// find an extension and its index
std::map<std::string,int>::iterator it2 = extMap.find( it->path().extension() );

if( it2 != extMap.end() ) {
    int index = it2->second;

    f[index].filePath = ...
}
```

Comment: You can initialize the map in a much more simple way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/138612/4323

Answer (score 1):

u have too much repeated code, u can make a method that takes an extension and return the folder it is supposed to be in, then store this file in the returned folder

Comment: Thanks.I would do that.But my main question is,is there a best way to group extensions and then use them.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to avoid the if-then conditions, but given that your are going to rework your code...

not knowing if you're working in a "secure environment", I would use [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301008/what-is-a-query-parameter-in-c) rather than constructing the query in a string. These are much better for handling [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

SQL injection is being one of the mostly exploited issues in application security and has found a place in OWASP Top 10 since 2004. There are many blog posts, papers available on SELECT query injection exploiting WHERE or HAVING clauses but there are also [SQL injection in INSERT query](http://amolnaik4.blogspot.it/2012/02/sql-injection-in-insert-query.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've had to use `auto` as I've got no idea what your types are. There's also no error checking (i.e. if an extension isn't matched).

```
auto path = it->path();
auto extension = path.extension();

int index = -1;
auto queryFolder = "";

    if (extension == ".txt" || extension == ".doc" || extension == ".docx" || extension == ".pdf") 
    {   
        index = 0;
        queryFolder = "Documents";
    }
    else if (extension == ".mp3" || extension == ".wma") 
    {      
        index = 1;
        queryFolder = "Music";
    }
    else if (extension == ".mp4") 
    {          
        index = 2;
        queryFolder = "Videos";
    }
    else if (extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".jpeg" || extension == ".gif") 
    {          
        index = 3;
        queryFolder = "Pictures";        
    }
    else 
    {     
        index = 4;
        queryFolder = "Others";
    }

    f[index].filePath = path;
    f[index].fileName = path.filename();
    f[index].fileExt = extension;     

    auto query = "Insert into Filemanager(Filepath,Filename,Category)values('" + f[index].filePath.string() + "','" + f[index].fileName.string() + "','";
    query += queryFolder;
    query += "')";
```